# How do you write to a new line when writing to a file in Python?

Tags: python, string, file, line

I'm trying to write some text to a file in Python. I use /n to try and create a new line but it just comes out like this in the file which is created:

Player 1 - \nBob - Score - 12 - Goals - 12

I would prefer it if the solution did not contain the os module, thanks.

EDIT: I've just realised this works on one computer and not another. I will get back to this tomorrow when I have access to the other PC.

Comment: Escapes always use `\\` , not `/`

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde Sorry typo, what I meant :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply do this:

```
f.write('some text\n')
```

Notice that the correct newline character is `'\n'`, not `'/n'`

Comment: There's no need for using two strings and +. You can just do `f.write('some text\n')` if you'd like.

Comment: Umm, I'm kind of confused, this is working atm on one of my PCs whereas on another it doesn't.. I will get back to you lot tomorrow as I have access to the PC then.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `\n`, rather than `/n`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in several ways.
My favorite is:

```
f = open('newfile.txt', 'w')
print >> f, "New String\n"
```

This `print >> filename, "someString"` synthax is convenient because it will remind you that you are writing  on the file exactly what you would print with the command: `print "someString"`